# Devise Omniauth "encrypted_password may not be NULL" for new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am using Devise with Omniauth to have users sign into my app with Facebook. I used the Railscast tutorials to get it up and running.

If a user is already a member of my site authenticating through facebook works fine. The problem comes in when authenticating a new user with facebook. When it goes to create a new user for my User model I get the "users.encrypted_password may not be NULL" error. I can't figure out how to pass over the password to the User model from Facebook information.

This is what I have:

authentations_controller.rb

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
 end

def create
  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'],   omniauth['uid'])
 if authentication
   flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
   sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
 elsif current_user
   current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
   flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
   redirect_to authentications_url
 else
   user = User.new
   user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
   if user.save
     flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
     sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
   else
     session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
     redirect_to new_user_registration_url
   end
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
 def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
  self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email'] if email.blank?
  authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
 end


 def password_required?
   (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
 end
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20] when creating a new user from facebook omniauth.

I believe Devise is expecting something in the password field to create a User.  Since there is no password when doing facebook oauth (not on your app side at least), you just need to create a dummy password as show above.

See this for more info:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had tried to implement this before but apparently incorrectly. All is working fine now. Hopefully that link may help someone else out.

Comment: and would can a user know what the password is?