# Devise OmniAuth - Auto Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am implementing Facebook Login on my App and have the following call back function. If the user is previously exisitant he should automatically be logged in.

**Error:**

```
    undefined method `user' for #<Oauth:0x007fbfb1194e20> on this row
sign_in_redirect(:user, oauth.user)
```

**Code:**

```
def facebook
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

    oauth = Oauth.find_by_provider_and_provider_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])

    if oauth
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in succefully."
      sign_in_redirect(:user, oauth.user)
    else
      user = User.new
      user.name = omniauth.info.name
      user.username = omniauth.info.nickname
      user.email = omniauth.info.email
      user.password = SecureRandom.hex(4)
      #user.gender = extra.raw_info.gender

      user_oauth = Oauth.new
      user_oauth.provider = omniauth.provider
      user_oauth.provider_uid = omniauth.uid
      user_oauth.oauth_token = omniauth.credentials.token
      user_oauth.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(omniauth.credentials.expires_at)

      if user.save!
        user.oauths << user_oauth
      end

      flash[:notice] = "Signed up succefully."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
```

Comment: Comparing your code with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641799/rails-devise-omniauth-with-facebook-login?rq=1 the difference in your code is this line `oauth = Oauth.find_by_provider_and_provider_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])`.Try changing it as `oauth = Oauth.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])`.

Comment: @Pavan my column is 'provider_uid' the error is in sign_in_and_redirect()

Comment: Show your Oauth model. You are probably missing a `belongs_to :user` statement. That's why the model has no `user` method.

Comment: damn 'sign_in_redirect' was supposed to be sign_in_and_redirect